# Creating JSON keys with array values in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that gets manipulated a few times. The end result is a data frame that looks like this:

```
    Company volume
1   NV      14
2   GD      8
3   AB      6
```

I covert this dataframe into json format like so:

```
formattedDF.to_json(orient='columns')
```

However, I get something like this:

```
'{"company":{"1":"NV","2":"GD","3":"AB"},"volume":{"1":14,"2":8,"3":6}}'
```

Which is very close to what I want, but the format I'm looking for is:

```
'{"company": ["NV", "GD","AB"], "volume":[14, 8, 6}]'
```

Where the keys give the values in array format instead. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Or:

```
print(df.to_dict(orient='list'))
```

Output:

```
{'Company': ['NV', 'GD', 'AB'], 'volume': [14, 8, 6]}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a dictionary comprehension:

```
{k: df[k].tolist() for k in df}
```

Or using `apply(list)`:

```
df.T.apply(list, 1).to_dict()
```

Both produce:

```
{'Company': ['NV', 'GD', 'AB'], 'volume': [14, 8, 6]}
```